# $A[x]$ points of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be an algebraic group. Specifically $O(n)$ or $Sp_{2n}$. Is it true that for any ring $A$ over $K$  , $G(A)\cong G(A[x])$. 
Is there any reference for such kind of results?

Comment: 1) "For a ring" means for some ring? for every ring? "a" is not a very clear quantifier. 2) $Sp_{2n}$ is not (at least to me) clearly defined as a scheme over $\mathbf{Z}$... there are several choices of symplectic forms, which do not matter over a field, but over a ring, it's less clear.

Comment: Certainly not with $G=\Bbb{G}_a$.

Comment: Yes, For G=$GL_n$  also it is not true. Thats why I asked for $O(n)$ and $Sp_{2n}$.

Comment: It is not true for $\operatorname{SL}_2 $, hence not for $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n} $.

Comment: @abx If $K$ is of infinite dimension over it prime subfield, call it $F$, then $\mathbb{G}_a(A)$ and $\mathbb{G}_a(A[x])$ are both $F$-vector spaces of $F$-dimension $\dim_FA=\aleph_0\cdot \dim_F A$ and are therefore isomorphic as abstract groups for any $K$-algebra $A$.

Comment: @ Uriya First: my understanding is that the OP asks whether the natural map $G(A)\rightarrow G(A[x])$ is an isomorphism. But of course this is not clearly formulated in the post.

Comment: @abx I agree. The map $G(A)\to G(A[x])$ is rarely an isomorphism. I understood the question as isomorphism of abstract groups.

Comment: @Girish, is your question about the existence of *some* group isomorphism $G(A)\cong G(A[x])$ or about the natural map $G(A)\to G(A[x])$ being an isomorphism?

Comment: @Uriya First I want the natural map to be isomorphism.

Comment: @Girish In that case, as soon as $G$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{G}_a$ as a closed subgroup, the map $G(A)\to G(A[x])$ will not be an isomorphism. This is always the case when $K$ is algebraically closed and $G=\mathrm{O}_n$ with $n>2$ or $\mathrm{Sp}_n$ with $n>1$ (the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup will contain such a copy). Since you can always take $A$ to  an algebraically closed field, $G(A)\to G(A[x])$ will not be an isomorphism  for all $A$-s when $G=\mathrm{O}_n$ or $\mathrm{Sp}_n$.

Comment: @UriyaFirst Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments show that the answer to the question is negative if $G$ contains a copy of $\mathbb G_a$. The examples $O(n)$ and $Sp(n)$ in the question suggest, though, that the emphasis is on anisotropic $G$. It is interesting that in this case the answer is affirmative to some extent.

Let, e.g., $K=\mathbb R$, let $G$ be a linear algebraic group not containing $\mathbb G_a$. This means that $G^0=SC$ where $S$ is a split torus and $C$ is anisotropic, i.e., $C(\mathbb R)$ is compact. Claim: Under these conditions $G(K)\overset\sim\to G(K[x])$.

An element of $G(K[x])$ is a morphism $f:\mathbb A^1\to G$. If $G=S$ then $f$ is constant since $K[x]^\times=K^\times$. If $G=C$ then the image of $f$ is closed. The reason for this is that $C$ is affine and therefore $f$ can't extend to $\mathbb P^1$. But, since $C(\mathbb R)$ is compact, the image of $\mathbf A^1(\mathbb R)$ in $C(\mathbb R)$ can't be closed unless $f$ is constant. The mixed case follows from these two subcases.

From this it follows easily that $G(A)\overset\sim\to G(A[x])$ when $A=\mathcal O(X)$ where $X$ is an irreducible normal affine $K$-variety such that $X(K)$ is Zariski dense in $X$.

With some effort, the argument can be extended to any field of characteristic zero.